# How to correct document validation fail in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, validation, collections

Ive created the following collection(the creation of which is successful)

```
db.createCollection("Company", { "validator": { "$jsonSchema": {
    "bsonType":"object",
    "required":["city_name","city","street_name","building_number","budget","Department"],
    "properties":{ "city_name":{ "bsonType":"string",
                            "description":"name of city" },
                   "city":{ "bsonType":"string",
                            "description":"City" },
                   "street_name":{ "bsonType":"string",
                                          "description" :"name of street" },
                   "building_number":{"bsonType":"int",
                                "description":"number of building", minimum: 0, maximum: 500},
                   "budget":{"bsonType":"double",
                                           "description":"budget of company",minimum: 0 },

                   "Department":{ "bsonType":"object",
                               "required":["Department_name","floor_number","Employee"],
                               "properties":{ "Department_name":{"bsonType":"string",
                                                        "description": "name of department" },
                                              "floor_number":{"bsonType":"int",
                                                      "description":"number of floor" },
                                             }},

                    "Employee":{ "bsonType":"object",
                                          "required":["first_name","last_name","DOB","Salary"],
                                          "properties":{"first_name":{"bsonType":"string",
                                                                "description":"Employees first name"},
                                                        "last_name":{"bsonType":"string",
                                                                 "description":"Employees last name"},
                                                        "DOB":{"bsonType":"date",
                                                                   "description":"Date of birth of empployee"},
                                                        "Salary":{"bsonType":"double",
                                                                   "description":"Salary of Employee",minimum: 0},
                                                        "Position":{"bsonType":"string",
                                                                   "description":"Position of employee. Field is not required"}}}}}}});
```

Ive created a set of data to insert into this collection to test the validations

```
db.Company.insert(
    { "city_name":"Sydney",
       "city":"Sydney",
       "street_name":"Pitt Street",
       "building_number":100,
       "budget": 100000.0,
       "Department":{"department_name":"Google",
                  "floor_number":4,
        "Employee" :{"first_name" : "George",
                     "last_name": "Martin",
                     "DOB": new Date('Dec 26,1981'),  
                     "Salary" : "70000",
                      "Position": "CEO"}}

     });
```

However when i run this script i get an error

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

Sadly Mongodb isnt very specific in what causes such errors and ive gone through my syntax and declarations and could not pick up on any errors myself,when clearly there is!

Why am i recieving this error when running my code? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**01)** Schema:

```
db.createCollection(
    "Company", 
    {
        "validator": { 
            "$jsonSchema": {
                "bsonType":"object",
                "required":["city_name","city","street_name","building_number","budget","Department"],
                "properties": { 
                    "city_name":{ "bsonType" : "string", "description" : "name of city" },
                    "city":{ "bsonType" : "string", "description" : "City" },
                    "street_name":{ "bsonType" : "string","description" : "name of street" },
                    "building_number": { "bsonType" : "int", "description" : "number of building", minimum: 0, maximum: 500},
                    "budget": { "bsonType" : "double", "description" : "budget of company",minimum: 0 },
                    "Department": { 
                        "bsonType":"object",
                        "required":["Department_name","floor_number","Employee"],
                        "properties": { 
                            "Department_name":{"bsonType":"string", "description": "name of department" },
                            "floor_number":{"bsonType":"int", "description":"number of floor" },
                            "Employee":{ 
                                "bsonType":"object",
                                "required":["first_name","last_name","DOB","Salary"],
                                "properties":{
                                    "first_name":{"bsonType":"string", "description":"Employees first name"},
                                    "last_name":{"bsonType":"string", "description":"Employees last name"},
                                    "DOB":{"bsonType":"date", "description":"Date of birth of empployee"},
                                    "Salary":{"bsonType":"double", "description":"Salary of Employee",minimum: 0},
                                    "Position":{"bsonType":"string", "description":"Position of employee. Field is not required"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**02)** Insert:

```
db.Company.insert(
{  
    "city_name": "Sydney",
    "city": "Sydney",
    "street_name": "Pitt Street",
    "building_number": NumberInt(100),
    "budget": 100000.0,
    "Department":{
        "Department_name":"Google",
        "floor_number": NumberInt(4),
        "Employee" : {
            "first_name" : "George",
            "last_name": "Martin",
            "DOB": new Date('Dec 26,1981'),  
            "Salary" : 70000.0,
            "Position": "CEO"
        }
    },    
});
```

I have to do a few changes:

- 'int' fields have to be NumberInt(number) in the insert command.
- The scheme has been changed so that 'Employee' is within 'Department'.
- Salary must be double.

Comment: Thankyou! Also may i ask, is that createCollection Schema using nesting? because i wanted to make department nested within company and then employee nested within department

Comment: Yes, in createCollectionSchema you can create a structure with nesting objects!

Answer (score 1):

`"Salary" : "70000"` is an `int`, but the schema ask for `double`:  `"Salary":{"bsonType":"double", "description":"Salary of Employee",minimum: 0},`.

I would recommend that you use the alias `"bsonType":"number"` in your schema instead of `int`,`double`, `long`, `decimal`. Since javascript is not typed, it can be a real pain to keep track which is used in your code.

See doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types

Comment: Ah okay. I didnt think it would be sensitive to that. I come from a java background so declaring a double as a whole number is second nature to me